# Is there a quick way to find which parent is being referenced by percentage sizings?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

Very often in css, I'll use percentage for width or height and find that it's not giving the result I'd expect.  From there, my next steps usually involve searching around through the parents, making sure `position: relative` exists where it should, or doesn't where it should not.

It's a very finicky process, and in the end, the first step is to find which element is the one I'm actually referencing with something like `width: 100%`.

Is there any quick way to do this?

Something along the line of `Element.sizeDefiningParent()`, or perhaps a trick to be used in one of the browsers dev tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again, writing the question led to the answer.  For those who use FireFox, it can be found in Dev Tools -> Layout Tab -> Box Model Dropdown -> position:

[image]